How to exit my try loop to get to the next code
I am trying to get the user to enter as many names and houses that they want until EOFerror, however the code keeps going to "input What is your name and house". Any idea why
import os
students = []
while True:
    try:
        newname, newhouse = input("what is your name and house? ").split(',')
    except ValueError: 
        print("You need to add a comma")
    except EOFError:
        nStudent = {'name': newname, 'house': newhouse}
        students.append(nStudent)
        with open(r"C:\Users\Student\Documents\mywebsites\python projects\students.csv") as file:
            for line in file:
                names, house = line.rstrip().split(',')
                student = {'name': names, 'house': house }
                students.append(student)
        break

            

def get_name(student):
    return student["name"]

for student in sorted(students, key=get_name):
    print(f"{student['name']} is in {student['house']}")
    


How are you generating EOFError?  Are you generating EOFError?

You're only appending the last student to the list. Is that really what you want? Wouldn't it make more sense to append each student to the list, and break out of the loop when you get EOFError?

That's what I'm trying to do. Any solutions
